# callback parameters arent accesable

Tags: node.js, express

I just started fiddling with node and I have a problem

```
mongoose = require "mongoose"
CalendarSchema = new mongoose.Schema
name: String

Calendar = mongoose.model('Calendar', CalendarSchema)

router = express.Router() # get an instance of the express Router

# Routes
# 
router.get "/calendars", (req, res) ->
  Calendar.find(error, calendars) ->
    if error
      res.send(error) 
    res.json(calendars)
    return

app.use('/api', router)
```

However, with this piece of code, I get an error saying

```
ReferenceError: error is not defined
```

Which refers to the callback arguments in the Calendar.find method, why is this?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Calendar.find (error, calendars) ->`, with whitespace before parenthesis?

Comment: Just bookmarking this for my arguments against CoffeeScript.